# Cypress running on a Docker image via Jenkins is hanging on first test

Tags: jenkins, cypress

I have a set of tests running locally using 'cypress run'. The target is a React app. They are also working within a docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:4.10.0 --env CLIENT_HOST= MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000 --config video=false --reporter junit --reporter-options \"mochaFile=results/cypress-report.xml,toConsole=true\"",
```

I have setup a simple Jenkins file running a similar npm command:

```
DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run --env CLIENT_HOST=MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000 --config video=false --reporter junit --reporter-options \"mochaFile=results/cypress-report.xml,toConsole=true\"
```

The steps to build the docker container and install cypress are working properly.
But when running the first test, it is hanging for several minutes before failing without any more information other than "wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file ...". Here is the last 100 lines of debug information. You can see that a first call seems to be made (first cy.visit(url)):
http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/first-endpoint

Anyway to get more information on what is actually hanging?

Thanks

````
[32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mGot first head bytes { url: [32m'fonts.googleapis.com:443'[39m, head: [32m'\u0016\u0003\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001�\u0003\u0003���r��ݬ�sL�\u000f�tT\u0001�|a6u�讇�̆� \r��b143:\u0013�Z�O\u0000�ЙrN���v���'[39m } [32m+16ms[0m
  [35;1mcypress:network:cors [0mParsed URL { port: [32m'443'[39m, tld: [32m'googleapis.com'[39m, domain: [32m'fonts'[39m } [35m+130ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mHTTPS request does not match URL: https://fonts.googleapis.com:443 with props: { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m } [31m+5ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mMaking connection to fonts.googleapis.com:443 [32m+2ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mgetting proxy URL { port: [33m443[39m, serverPort: [33m43549[39m, sniPort: [33m38471[39m, url: [32m'https://fonts.googleapis.com:443'[39m } [32m+1ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0mreceived status code & headers on request { requestId: [32m'request4'[39m, statusCode: [33m200[39m, headers: { [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m } } [34m+135ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0msuccessful response received { requestId: 'request4' } [34m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mLeaving stage { stage: [32m'IncomingRequest'[39m } [31m+7ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mEntering stage { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'LogResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mreceived response { req: { method: [32m'GET'[39m, proxiedUrl: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/static/js/bundle.js'[39m, headers: { host: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, [32m'proxy-connection'[39m: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'user-agent'[39m: [32m'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/4.1.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.130 Electron/7.1.13 Safari/537.36'[39m, accept: [32m'*/*'[39m, referer: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/first-endpoint'[39m, [32m'accept-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, [32m'accept-language'[39m: [32m'en-US'[39m } }, incomingRes: { headers: { [32m'x-powered-by'[39m: [32m'Express'[39m, [32m'accept-ranges'[39m: [32m'bytes'[39m, [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m, etag: [32m'W/"7c91-cPkatRF59dkzrye1hs21A5BQAT0"'[39m, vary: [32m'Accept-Encoding'[39m, [32m'content-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, date: [32m'Fri, 10 Jul 2020 14:34:28 GMT'[39m, connection: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'transfer-encoding'[39m: [32m'chunked'[39m }, statusCode: [33m200[39m } } [32m+72ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'PatchExpressSetHeader'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SetInjectionLevel'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0minjection levels: { isInitial: [33mfalse[39m, wantsInjection: [33mfalse[39m, wantsSecurityRemoved: [33mtrue[39m } [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'OmitProblematicHeaders'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybePreventCaching'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyCookiesFromIncomingRes'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeSendRedirectToClient'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyResponseStatusCode'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'ClearCyInitialCookie'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mGetting remote state: { auth: [1mnull[22m, props: { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m }, origin: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, strategy: [32m'http'[39m, visiting: [33mfalse[39m, domainName: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, fileServer: [1mnull[22m } [31m+5ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeEndWithEmptyBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeGunzipBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mungzipping response body [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeInjectHtml'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeRemoveSecurity'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mremoving JS framebusting code [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'GzipBody'[39m } [31m+2ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mregzipping response body [32m+2ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SendResponseBodyToClient'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:network:connect [0msuccessfully connected { opts: { port: [32m'443'[39m, host: [32m'fonts.googleapis.com'[39m, getDelayMsForRetry: [36m[Function: getDelayForRetry][39m }, iteration: [33m0[39m } [32m+404ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mreceived upstreamSocket callback for request { port: [32m'443'[39m, hostname: [32m'fonts.googleapis.com'[39m, err: [90mundefined[39m } [32m+28ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:server:util:socket_whitelist [0mwhitelisting socket { localPort: [33m60442[39m } [32m+402ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0mreceived status code & headers on request { requestId: [32m'request5'[39m, statusCode: [33m200[39m, headers: { [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m } } [34m+31ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0msuccessful response received { requestId: 'request5' } [34m+0ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0mreceived status code & headers on request { requestId: [32m'request6'[39m, statusCode: [33m200[39m, headers: { [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m } } [34m+1ms[0m
  [34;1mcypress:server:request [0msuccessful response received { requestId: 'request6' } [34m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mLeaving stage { stage: [32m'IncomingRequest'[39m } [31m+26ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mLeaving stage { stage: [32m'IncomingRequest'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mEntering stage { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'LogResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mreceived response { req: { method: [32m'GET'[39m, proxiedUrl: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js'[39m, headers: { host: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, [32m'proxy-connection'[39m: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'user-agent'[39m: [32m'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/4.1.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.130 Electron/7.1.13 Safari/537.36'[39m, accept: [32m'*/*'[39m, referer: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/first-endpoint'[39m, [32m'accept-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, [32m'accept-language'[39m: [32m'en-US'[39m } }, incomingRes: { headers: { [32m'x-powered-by'[39m: [32m'Express'[39m, [32m'accept-ranges'[39m: [32m'bytes'[39m, [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m, etag: [32m'W/"7f412e-m0dw6Pe1V54+v5GbcYMYgnO5a/g"'[39m, vary: [32m'Accept-Encoding'[39m, [32m'content-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, date: [32m'Fri, 10 Jul 2020 14:34:28 GMT'[39m, connection: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'transfer-encoding'[39m: [32m'chunked'[39m }, statusCode: [33m200[39m } } [32m+27ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'PatchExpressSetHeader'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SetInjectionLevel'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0minjection levels: { isInitial: [33mfalse[39m, wantsInjection: [33mfalse[39m, wantsSecurityRemoved: [33mtrue[39m } [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'OmitProblematicHeaders'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybePreventCaching'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyCookiesFromIncomingRes'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeSendRedirectToClient'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyResponseStatusCode'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'ClearCyInitialCookie'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mGetting remote state: { auth: [1mnull[22m, props: { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m }, origin: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, strategy: [32m'http'[39m, visiting: [33mfalse[39m, domainName: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, fileServer: [1mnull[22m } [31m+32ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeEndWithEmptyBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeGunzipBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mungzipping response body [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeInjectHtml'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeRemoveSecurity'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mremoving JS framebusting code [32m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'GzipBody'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mregzipping response body [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SendResponseBodyToClient'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mEntering stage { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'LogResponse'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mreceived response { req: { method: [32m'GET'[39m, proxiedUrl: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js'[39m, headers: { host: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, [32m'proxy-connection'[39m: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'user-agent'[39m: [32m'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/4.1.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.130 Electron/7.1.13 Safari/537.36'[39m, accept: [32m'*/*'[39m, referer: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/first-endpoint'[39m, [32m'accept-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, [32m'accept-language'[39m: [32m'en-US'[39m } }, incomingRes: { headers: { [32m'x-powered-by'[39m: [32m'Express'[39m, [32m'accept-ranges'[39m: [32m'bytes'[39m, [32m'content-type'[39m: [32m'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'[39m, etag: [32m'W/"17afae-v4sc2chbHgsw13KNvg7tgkJ0wnw"'[39m, vary: [32m'Accept-Encoding'[39m, [32m'content-encoding'[39m: [32m'gzip'[39m, date: [32m'Fri, 10 Jul 2020 14:34:28 GMT'[39m, connection: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'transfer-encoding'[39m: [32m'chunked'[39m }, statusCode: [33m200[39m } } [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'PatchExpressSetHeader'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SetInjectionLevel'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0minjection levels: { isInitial: [33mfalse[39m, wantsInjection: [33mfalse[39m, wantsSecurityRemoved: [33mtrue[39m } [32m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'OmitProblematicHeaders'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybePreventCaching'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyCookiesFromIncomingRes'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeSendRedirectToClient'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'CopyResponseStatusCode'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'ClearCyInitialCookie'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mGetting remote state: { auth: [1mnull[22m, props: { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m }, origin: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, strategy: [32m'http'[39m, visiting: [33mfalse[39m, domainName: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, fileServer: [1mnull[22m } [31m+3ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeEndWithEmptyBody'[39m } [31m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeGunzipBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mungzipping response body [32m+1ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeInjectHtml'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'MaybeRemoveSecurity'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mremoving JS framebusting code [32m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'GzipBody'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:proxy:http:response-middleware [0mregzipping response body [32m+0ms[0m
  [31;1mcypress:proxy:http [0mRunning middleware { stage: [32m'IncomingResponse'[39m, middlewareName: [32m'SendResponseBodyToClient'[39m } [31m+0ms[0m

  [32;1mcypress:server:browsers:electron [0mconsole message: { column: [33m15[39m, level: [32m'log'[39m, line: [33m219188[39m, source: [32m'console-api'[39m, text: [32m'[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...'[39m, url: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js'[39m } [32m+2s[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mGot CONNECT request from MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000 [31m+1s[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mWriting browserSocket connection headers { url: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, headLength: [33m0[39m, headers: { host: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, [32m'proxy-connection'[39m: [32m'keep-alive'[39m, [32m'user-agent'[39m: [32m'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/4.1.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.130 Electron/7.1.13 Safari/537.36'[39m } } [32m+1s[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mGot first head bytes { url: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m, head: [32m'GET /sockjs-node HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000\r\nConnection: Upgrade'[39m } [32m+2ms[0m
  [35;1mcypress:network:cors [0mParsed URL { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m } [35m+1s[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mHTTPS request does match URL: https://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000 with props: { port: [32m'3000'[39m, tld: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN'[39m, domain: [32m''[39m } [31m+4ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mNot making direct connection { url: [32m'MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000'[39m } [32m+2ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mMaking intercepted connection to 43549 [32m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mgetting proxy URL { port: [33m43549[39m, serverPort: [33m43549[39m, sniPort: [33m38471[39m, url: [32m'https://localhost:43549'[39m } [32m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:network:connect [0msuccessfully connected { opts: { port: [33m43549[39m, host: [32m'localhost'[39m, getDelayMsForRetry: [36m[Function: getDelayForRetry][39m }, iteration: [33m0[39m } [32m+1s[0m
  [32;1mcypress:https-proxy [0mreceived upstreamSocket callback for request { port: [33m43549[39m, hostname: [32m'localhost'[39m, err: [90mundefined[39m } [32m+6ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:server:util:socket_whitelist [0mwhitelisting socket { localPort: [33m53374[39m } [32m+1s[0m
  [31;1mcypress:server:server [0mGot UPGRADE request from /sockjs-node [31m+6ms[0m
  [33;1mcypress:network:agent [0maddRequest called { isHttps: [33mfalse[39m, href: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/sockjs-node'[39m } [33m+1s[0m
  [33;1mcypress:network:agent [0mgot family { family: [33m4[39m, href: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/sockjs-node'[39m } [33m+0ms[0m
  [32;1mcypress:server:browsers:electron [0mconsole message: { column: [33m21[39m, level: [32m'info'[39m, line: [33m128248[39m, source: [32m'console-api'[39m, text: [32m'%cDownload the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://someurl.me/react-devtools font-weight:bold'[39m, url: [32m'http://MY_DEV_DOMAIN:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js'[39m } [32m+21ms[0m

HANGING```
````